# Physical meaning of Schmidt states

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, tensor-network

Given a bipartite system AB (where A and B are the subsystems), a generic pure quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ on AB can be Schmidt-decomposed into:

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \sum_\alpha^{r}s_\alpha |\alpha\rangle_A|\alpha\rangle_B
\end{equation}
Where $N_A, N_B$ are the dimensions of the Hilbert spaces of subsystems A and B, respectively, and $r$ is the number of non-zero Schmidt values $s_\alpha$. I know that from the Schmidt values $s_\alpha$ we can readily obtain the entanglement entropy:
\begin{equation}
S_{A||B}(|\psi\rangle)=-\sum_\alpha^{r}s_\alpha^2\log s_\alpha^2
\end{equation}
And that the Schmidt states are eigenstates of the reduced density matrices, as:
\begin{equation}
\rho_{A}=\sum_\alpha^r s_\alpha^2|\alpha\rangle_{A\hspace{0.1cm}A}\langle \alpha|
\end{equation}
And similarly for B.

What I don't get is what the physical meaning of all this is. Some questions I have are:

1. What do the Schmidt states represent?
2. What is the intuitive reason why the reduced density matrices are in a mixture of the same number of Schmidt states?

Comment: Schmidt states represent the preferred basis, in which result of measurements on $A$ and $B$ are fully correlated: if we have found $A$ in $\vert \alpha\rangle_A$ state, then we will found $B$ in $\vert \alpha\rangle_B$ state for sure.